# c++ use typedef with LegacyRandomAccessIterator

Tags: c++

I learned about `std::vector` data type in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). at the moment in Member types, I saw `iterator` data_type.

I did know `iterator` requirements `LegacyRandomAccessIterator`. but how can I define `LegacyRandomAccessIterator iterator` data_type with my own template class?

```cpp
template <typename T>
class vec {
    typedef  T value_type;//correct
    typedef LegacyRandomAccessIterator iterator;//error
};
```

I tried using `typedef LegacyRandomAccessIterator iterator`, but failed. how can I define an `iterator` represents `LegacyRandomAccessIterator` in my custom class?

Comment: "LegacyRandomAccessIterator" is not a class or a type, it's a *concept* for random-access iterators.

Comment: `LegacyRandomAccessIterator` is a concept in c++, where can I found `vector<T>::iterator` implementation code?

Comment: Generally I don't recommend looking at the implementation for the standard library of any of the major compilers. The code highly optimized, and very hard to read for beginners or even more advanced C++ programmers. It requires intimate knowledge of the standard library and the concepts being implemented.

Comment: If you really want to look at an implementation libc++ is here: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/iterator#L1337

Comment: So first learn C++ with all it entails, most specifically (for this issue) operator overloading. Then read about [legacy random access iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) and the operations it needs to support. Then use your knowledge of classes and operator overloading to create your own implementation. That will teach you much more than reading the almost obfuscated implementations of the big compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a type with the following operators, with the same meanings as they have with pointers.

```
template <typename T>
class vec_iterator
{
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;

    vec_iterator();

    reference operator*();
    pointer operator->();

    vec_iterator& operator++();
    vec_iterator operator++(int);
    vec_iterator& operator--();
    vec_iterator operator--(int);

    vec_iterator& operator+=(difference_type);
    vec_iterator& operator-=(difference_type);

    reference operator[](difference_type);
};

template <typename T>
bool operator ==(vec_iterator<T>, vec_iterator<T>);
template <typename T>
bool operator !=(vec_iterator<T>, vec_iterator<T>);

template <typename T>
bool operator <(vec_iterator<T>, vec_iterator<T>);
template <typename T>
bool operator <=(vec_iterator<T>, vec_iterator<T>);
template <typename T>
bool operator >(vec_iterator<T>, vec_iterator<T>);
template <typename T>
bool operator >=(vec_iterator<T>, vec_iterator<T>);

template <typename T>
vec_iterator<T> operator +(vec_iterator<T>, typename vec_iterator<T>::difference_type);
template <typename T>
vec_iterator<T> operator +(typename vec_iterator<T>::difference_type, vec_iterator<T>);

template <typename T>
vec_iterator<T> operator -(vec_iterator<T>, typename vec_iterator<T>::difference_type);
template <typename T>
vec_iterator<T> operator -(typename vec_iterator<T>::difference_type, vec_iterator<T>);
```

Note that `T*` is a type that satisfies *RandomAccessIterator*.

The non-members with `vec_iterator` as the leftmost parameter can instead be members. Instead of providing `difference_type`, `value_type`, `pointer`, `reference` and `iterator_category`, you can provide a (partial) specialisation `std::iterator_traits<vec_iterator<T>>` with those typedefs.